# Callback method before deallocating any Object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

Is there any way to call a method before deallocating any NSObject Class object.

or

Is it possible to writing custom dealloc method for NSObject Class so that
we can call any method before deallocating that object?

As garbage collector is not available for iPhone, I wants to create small framework which handles memory leak at runtime & create a log files for leaks (I known that there is instrument that identify the leaks but still for R&D and don't want to implement Garbage Collector algo).

We are trying to maintain a list of allocated object.

for example:

```
A *a=[[A alloc]init];

NSString * veribaleAddress=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%p",&a];

NSString *allocatedMemoryAddress=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%p",a];

// Global dictionary for maintaining a list of object  NSMutableDictionary *objects;


[objects setValue: allocatedMemoryAddress forKey: veribaleAddress];
```

but when any object get deallocate then I want to 1st look, whether address of that object is present in dictionary or not. If address present then remove it from dictionary.

Please guide me, whether it's possible or not.

Thanks

Comment: You’ll get better answers if you tell us what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: You might be able to swizzle `-[NSObject dealloc]` but that’s generally A Bad Idea™. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you properly. Do you want to call a method in dealloc or before dealloc. I suppose you know that You never send a dealloc message directly. Instead, an object’s dealloc method is invoked indirectly through the release NSObject protocol method (if the release message results in the receiver's retain count becoming 0)

Comment: Hi All, I have again edit my question. please check it.

Comment: a) you should not do this b) if you're still convinced it is worthwhile, your implementation will need a significant redesign c) you should not do this

Answer (score 9):

Here’s an [example gist](https://gist.github.com/672643) showing how to [swizzle](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-01-29-method-replacement-for-fun-and-profit.html) the `dealloc` method, if that’s what you are after. Main part of the code:

```
void swizzle(Class c, SEL orig, SEL patch)
{
    Method origMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(c, orig);
    Method patchMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(c, patch);

    BOOL added = class_addMethod(c, orig,
        method_getImplementation(patchMethod),
        method_getTypeEncoding(patchMethod));

    if (added) {
        class_replaceMethod(c, patch,
            method_getImplementation(origMethod),
            method_getTypeEncoding(origMethod));
        return;
    }

    method_exchangeImplementations(origMethod, patchMethod);
}

id swizzledDealloc(id self, SEL _cmd)
{
    // …whatever…
    return self;
}

const SEL deallocSel  = @selector(dealloc);
// If using ARC, try:
//  const SEL deallocSel  = NSSelectorFromString(@"dealloc");

const SEL swizzledSel = @selector(swizzledDealloc);
class_addMethod(c, swizzledSel, (IMP) swizzledDealloc, "@@:");
swizzle(c, deallocSel, swizzledSel);
```

As Bavarious says, this is dark magic and I wouldn’t use it in production, ever.

Comment: +1 for being the first one to detail the right way to do it ('right' in the sense that it is how one *would* approach implementing something that *should never* exist)

Comment: +1 echoing the reservations of you and Justin, but swizzling is a legitimate tool in rare circumstances - I think this is how KVO is implemented.

Comment: BTW swizzledDealloc needs to invoke the original dealloc or the object will not actually get deallocated.

Comment: I have customize the swizzelDealloc code as follows ,
As I need method call back for every object that get dealloc, so I swizzle the dealloc method of NSObject Class

for that I create category of NSObject  & add swizzelDealloc method in that as follows..

'-(void)swizzledDealloc'
{
    //call to handler method…

 classplaceDeallocated([self class]); 
 [self dealloc];//call default implementation of dealloc method..
 classReplaceDeallocated([self class]);
}'

Comment: I'm f... I did swizzle the dealloc for UIVIew a month ago, now I realize UIViews gets randomly released when dealloc is called. I'm screwed got to tell my boss my magic doesn't work anymore... I'm proof that swizzle the dealloc is... a failure

Comment: @JeremyP KVO uses ISA-pointer Swizzling (adds functionality to a single instance) while the above example uses dispatch-table swizzling. . this late-binding is what makes Objective-C a dynamic language.

Answer (score 5):

You might be able to use [objc_setAssociatedObject](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocAssociativeReferences.html) to track the lifespan of the object.  Something like this:

Header:

```
// SGBObjectTracker.h

typedef void (^SGBObjectTrackerCallback)(id trackedObject); 

@interface SGBObjectTracker : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, assign) id trackedObject;
@property (nonatomic, copy) SGBObjectTrackerCallback callback;

+(void) trackObject:(id)object withCallback:(SGBObjectTrackerCallback)callback;

@end
```

Implementation:

```
// SGBObjectTracker.m

#import "SGBObjectTracker.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation 

@synthesize trackedObject, callback;

-(void) dealloc
{
    callback(trackedObject);
    [super dealloc];
}

+(void) trackObject:(id)object withCallback:(SGBObjectTrackerCallback)callback
{
    SGBObjectTracker *tracker = [[self alloc] init];
    tracker.callback = callback;
    tracker.trackedObject = object;
    objc_setAssociatedObject(object, _cmd, tracker, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
    [tracker release];
}

@end
```

This takes advantage of the fact that associated objects are released when the objects they are associated with are dealloced.  It won't work with NSZombies enabled, and it may break if you're using ARC or something else which messes about with retain counts.  I wouldn't count on being able to use the object in question during the callback, but its address should still be OK and that's what you seem to need.

Comment: Associated objects are released AFTER the parent object's ivars get cleaned out, so it's not useful for e.g. unregistering KVO.